# Adding a closure to a swift function reading from a firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, closures

I have a function which makes a call to a Firebase DB and returns a quote based on the date. Because the data is not read immediately, the function returns before the data is applied. How can I add a closure so that I can avoid this? I added the 'prints' to show how the function is processing.

Thanks!

```
func getQuoteFromDate(database: Firestore, dateVal: String) -> String {
    var dailyQuoteText = "Quote Text Base"
    let dbRef = database.collection("dailyQuotes")
    dbRef.whereField("date", isEqualTo: dateVal).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
         if err != nil {
                dailyQuoteText = "Unable to Get Quote"
                print("Failed to get the item")
             } else {
                 for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print("Checking for date " + dateVal)
                    let quoteVal = document.get("quote") as! String
                    let authorVal = document.get("author") as! String
                    dailyQuoteText = quoteVal + "\n\n -" + authorVal
                    print("Writing the quote " + dailyQuoteText)
                 }
             }
     }
    print("Returning the quote " + dailyQuoteText)
    return dailyQuoteText
}
```

Output:

> Returning the quote Quote Text Base
>
> Checking for date 2020-04-05

Writing the quote Things work out best for those who make the best of how things work out.

Answer (score 1):

You have a design flaw. Calls to Firestore are asynchronous. You need to change your design philosophy. For example:

```
var dailyQuoteText:String = "Quote Text Base" {
    didSet {
        dailyQuoteFetched()
    }
}

var dateVal:String = "" {
    didSet {
        fetchNewDailyQuote(database:db)
    }
}

func fetchNewDailyQuote(database: Firestore) {
    // Here you could show a spinner to your users so 
    // that they would know that you are fetching info
    let dbRef = database.collection("dailyQuotes")
    dbRef.whereField("date", isEqualTo: dateVal).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
         if err != nil {
                self.dailyQuoteText = "Unable to Get Quote"
                print("Failed to get the item")
             } else {
                 for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print("Checking for date " + dateVal)
                    let quoteVal = document.get("quote") as! String
                    let authorVal = document.get("author") as! String
                    self.dailyQuoteText = quoteVal + "\n\n -" + authorVal
                    print("Writing the quote " + dailyQuoteText)
                 }
             }
     }
}

func dailyQuoteFetched() {
    // New quote is ready. Hide your spinner and display it
}
```